# how to get a value from NSSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitouch, nsset

I have printed an NSSet like below

```
touch :<UITouch: 0x9266b60>
    phase: Began
    tap count: 1
    window: <UIWindow: 0x718a240;
frame  = (0 0; 320 480);
layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x718a050>>
view: <UILabel: 0x7588b60; 
frame = (60  17; 69 16);
text = '11:30-11:45 AM';
clipsToBounds = YES;
opaque = NO; 
autoresize = RM+BM;
tag = 2;
layer = <CALayer: 0x7588bf0>>
    location in window: {102, 233} 
    previous location in  window: {102, 233}
    location in view: {38, 5}
    previous location in view: {38, 5}
```

I want to take out only the value for key **text =**
How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you explain where the set is from? Hard to understand what type of data you have got.

Comment: I am printing the value where the touch is on the screen,by NSTouch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the timestamp property of the [UITouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object if you're looking for the time the touch happened.

Answer (score 1):

Using the method - (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key ?